# Save converted image into specific path in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, file-conversion

Can someone explain to me how to save our converted image (from *.ppm into *.pgm) in specific directory in matlab..

Here is my code.

```
     pathName = 'D:\Matlab\Training\PGM_Files';
     % Create it if it doesn't exist.
     if ~exist(pathName, 'dir')
     mkdir(pathName);
     % This will create to the full depth of the path.
     % Upper folder levels don't have to exist yet.
     end
     fullFileName = fullfile(pathName);

     pgm_File_Images(loop1,1)=imwrite((Train_Images,['data',num2str(loop1),'.pgm']),
     fullFileName);
```

I want to save all my file into folder **PGM_Files**. 
But everytime I got error

```
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

How to fix it??

Comment: Have you read the error message? Somewhere your brackets do not match.

Comment: When I run that code, I got the error mssg "Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [." But my bracket is already right.. I dont know what's wrong with that code

Comment: As a hint: Look for a single `]` to which there is no `[`.

Comment: I already try it but still same

Comment: You don't provide the [right kind of input arguments to `imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html). That's why the last `)` claims to be unmatched.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already given in the comments, I will thus post it here to make sure the question does not remain unanswered:

> You don't provide the right kind of input arguments to imwrite. That's
>   why the last ) claims to be unmatched.